# What is causing the segmentation fault in this function?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am writing a function to search through a 2D array of characters for words from a list. I am encountering a segmentation fault,probably because of the while loop I have set up according to the backtrace, but I can't see what is causing it.

Here is the code for the function that I believe the error is in. Note: This is just the part for the horizontal search.

```
void searchWord(int j, int k, int gridsize, char** arr, char** list, int listPos){
if(j+strlen(*(list+listPos)) <= gridsize){ //Horizontal
    int i = 0;
    while(i < strlen(*(list+listPos)) && *(*(arr+(j+i))+k) == *(*(list+(listPos+i)))){
        i++;
    }
    if(i == strlen(*(list+listPos))){
        while(i > 0 && *(*(arr+(j+i))+k) == *(*(list+(listPos+i)))){
        tolower(*(*(arr+(j+i))+k));
        i--;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < strlen(*(list+listPos)); i++)
            printf("%c", *(*(list+listPos)+i));
    }
}
```

This is what the backtrace is telling me.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000008000fd2 in searchWord (j=0, k=0, gridsize=15, arr=0x8403260, list=0x84032e0, listPos=49)
    at arraysearch.c:110
110                     while(i < strlen(*(list+listPos)) && *(*(arr+(j+i))+k) == *(*(list+(listPos+i)))){
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000008000fd2 in searchWord (j=0, k=0, gridsize=15, arr=0x8403260, list=0x84032e0, listPos=49)
    at arraysearch.c:110
#1  0x0000000008000ed4 in searchPuzzle (arr=0x8403260, n=15, list=0x84032e0, listSize=50) at arraysearch.c:96
#2  0x0000000008000d70 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7ffffffee048) at arraysearch.c:68
```

Comment: It will make the code easier to read to use `x[y]` notation rather than `*(x+y)`

Comment: `tolower(X)` has no effect, `tolower` is a macro/function that reads the input and returns its output

Comment: You probably access out of bounds of `arr` or `list` but it is impossible to say without seeing the whole program  , please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the segmentation fault. I was accessing the word in the list instead of the letter in the words.

```
*(*(list+(listPos+i)))
```

Needed to be

```
*(*(list+listPos)+i)
```